# Best way to maintain multiple related projects in one git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, multi-project

As part of a personal project, I've started to use git instead of subversion, maybe I'm learning something new from that.

Setting up the repository was fairly easy, configuring my web server to serve the git file works like a charm; commiting, cloning, no problem here.

However, I have some issues with my project setup within the repository. Currently it looks like this:

```
project.git
\- mobileapp
\- artwork
\- backend
\- website
```

`website` and `mobileapp` are supposed to communicate with `backend` once everything works.

My problem now is the deployment: When I want to deploy the `backend` on my server, currently I'd need to checkout the whole repository and copy the contents from `backend` to my webroot dir.

As there seems to be no way to just checkout the contents of `project.git/backend`, I am thinking of separating the four subprojects into four git repositories, with the added overhead of maintaining four repositories.

Is there an easier way to solve my problem?

Comment: submodules could be useful

Comment: What about just doing what you do now, cloning to some location on your server and then using a post-hook that copies backend to the production area after it receives,  and restarts whatever server processes neccessary?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that there is no particularly easy way to checkout a partial Git repository. (As of 1.7.0, Git has support for [sparse checkout](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) but that may not address your needs.)

The typical recommendation is to put each logically separate module into a separate repository. Managing the relationship between these modules is somewhat difficult.

One approach is to use [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). This adds metadata inside a parent Git repository that teaches Git how to checkout the appropriate versions of child repositories. You then manage the relationship by making individual commits that bump that metadata.

Another is to use an external tool like Android's [repo](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html) tool. Repo maintains its own state regarding the multiple child repositories as well, but unlike sub-modules, which is very revision focused, `repo` is more branch focused.

The two approaches are both workable and show a philosophical difference in how to think about the relationship between modules. This is not necessarily a "simpler" way to solve your problem, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use `submodule`:

```
$ git submodule -h
```

E.g.

```
$ git submodule add git@github.com:<username>/backend.git backend
```

Then you can also treat `backend` as a separate project.